# Pickers in List() are disabled despite being inside NavigationView

Tags: swiftui

I have a view to control settings in an app. The view is composed of a list of segmented pickers. The preview and sim run display appropriately, but all the pickers are greyed out. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Below is a runnable code sample.

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var distSetting:Int = 0
    @Published var tempSetting:Int = 0
    @Published var pressSetting:Int = 0
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var settings = UserSettings()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack{
            Text("Unit Settings")
            
                List{
                    Section{
                        Text("Temperature")
                        Picker("Temperature", selection: $settings.tempSetting, content: {
                            Text("F°")
                            Text("C°")
                            Text("K°")
                        })
                        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    }
                    Section{
                        Text("Pressure")
                        Picker("Pressure", selection: $settings.pressSetting, content: {
                            Text("millibar")
                            Text("inches Hg")
                            Text("hPa")
                        }).pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    }
                    Section{
                        Text("Distance")
                        Picker("Distance", selection: $settings.distSetting, content: {
                            Text("nm")
                            Text("sm")
                            Text("km")
                        }).pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    }
                }
                .listSectionSpacing(6)
                
                Spacer()
            }   // end Nav
        }       // end outer VStack
    }           // end View
}               // end Struct

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `.tag(...)` to the entries in the `Picker`s. Without the tags the picker won't know what option refers to what value.
E.g.

```
Picker(....) {
    Text("some option 1").tag(0)
    Text("some option 2").tag(1)
    Text("some option 3").tag(1)
}
```

You can also use other types than `Int`, you might just need to make your type conform to `Hashable`, e.g. if you are using an enum for the temperature units etc.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I needed to tag the items, but was distracted by the disabled controls in the View. Now I know that the tag type must be harmonious with the bound type before the picker will activate. This was not clearly stated in the docs I read.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `$settings.tempSetting` is `Int`, on other hand, Picker elements are `String`. It cannot map by index this way.

Second, Picker elements need an ID to be recognized or it will be re-render as a new view whenever $selection changes.

Try this:

```swift
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    ...
    @Published var tempSetting: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    ...
    var temps = ["F", "C", "K"]

    var body: some View {
        ...
        Picker("Temperature", selection: $settings.tempSetting, content: {
            ForEach(temps, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        })
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
    }
}
```

You can do `distSetting` and `pressSetting` the same way. I recommend a change from `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject` since its scope is inside this view, and remove `@Published`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment!  I am using an Observable because the settings need to be accessible in other parts of the App. My grasp of SwiftUI dataflow is still very fragile at this point!